# AutoHotKey iOS double space script

Tags: ios, autohotkey

In iOS there's an option in Settings > General > Keyboard called '"." Shortcut'. When enabled, "Double tapping the space bar will insert a period followed by a space" and automatically capitalizes the next letter.

Does anyone know how to go abouts creating an AutoHotKey script to do this, as I find it extremely useful in iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ben,

You could try this:

```
~$Space:: ; trigger on {Space}
if (A_PriorHotkey <> "~$Space" or A_TimeSincePriorHotkey > 250)
    Return
SendInput, {BS 2}.{Space}
Input, NextKey, I L1 T10 V B, {LControl}{RControl}{LAlt}{RAlt}{LShift}{RShift}{LWin}{RWin}{AppsKey}{F1}{F2}{F3}{F4}{F5}{F6}{F7}{F8}{F9}{F10}{F11}{F12}{Left}{Right}{Up}{Down}{Home}{End}{PgUp}{PgDn}{Del}{Ins}{BS}{Capslock}{Numlock}{PrintScreen}{Pause}

If NextKey and NextKey is lower
    SendInput, {BS}+%NextKey%
Return
```

Comment: I recommend using `~$Space` as the hotkey.  It'll prevent any potential issues with sending Space triggering the hotkey.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand, thank you for this valuable addition, preventing the send {Space} from potentially triggering itself...

Comment: There does seem to be an issue with it, I've just noticed. When you press double space you can't immediately backspace - you have to enter another character before you can.

Comment: Ben,  Could it be that you only added the $ to the trigger? If so add it to the IF statement as well.

Comment: @Robert Nope. A direct copy-and-paste from the code box and still the same issue. :/

Comment: By default the Input command checks for backspace, and removes the last character it knows of from the output variable (it usually makes sense).  I modified the code to cancel the capitalizing if another key (like backspace) is pressed.  It also now doesn't block the input (V for Visible in the options).  It only makes a correction if NextKey is a lowercase letter.

Comment: Further request: Is there a way to restrict this so the function only executes if the last key pressed was a space? I type so fast it's replacing `a` with `. `.

Comment: The line `If NextKey and NextKey is lower` is an error: `if var is type` cannot be combined with an expression. Instead, it is interpreted as `If NextKey and NextKey . is . lower`, where `is` and `lower` are (empty) variables.